# the best way to organize interface to private member vector<vector<Type>>

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, iterator, stdvector

Supposing, I have a class:

```
class Class
{
private:
   std::vector <std::vector <Type>> vec2d;
   // Or, for example, something like this:
   std::vector <std::vector <std::shared_ptr <Type>> vec2dptr;
}
```

And I need to organize interface to a private vector. The size of a vector may rich thousands elements. What is the best solution (memory/performance)?

As a variant, I can return a pair of iterators from getter (begin(), end()):

```
std::pair <std::vector <const std::vector <const Type>>::iterator,
           std::vector <const std::vector <const Type>>::iterator>
           GetPrimaryVectorRange();

// To get an element from sub-vector, pass iterator of main vector to getter
std::pair <std::vector <const Type>::iterator,
           std::vector <const Type>::iterator>
           GetSecondaryVectorRange(
           std::vector <const std::vector <const Type>>::const_iterator primary_elem );
```

The simpliest way is to return a vector by constant value, but then a copy constructor will be called, not move constructor from C++11, am I right? Is there any standart approach or pattern in this case?

Comment: The simplest is to return a const reference to it, which won't involve copying. But it's hard to follow for me what the problem is. Don't "organize an interface to a vector". Create an interface that correctly resembles logic and concepts you wish to model in your program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your API returning a pair of `std::vector` iterators already makes it public knowledge that the rows of your 2d array are `std::vector`s, so you might as well keep it simple and do something like

```
std::vector<Type> const &operator[](size_t i) const { return vec2d[i]; }
std::vector<Type> &operator[](size_t i) { return vec2d[i]; }
```

And let your callers extract the iterator themselves if they need iterators:

```
auto row = arr[i];
auto iter = std::find(row.begin(), row.end(), 42);
```

If all the rows of your array are the same length, consider writing a simple 2D array class (or using [mine](https://github.com/jpreiss/array2d)) that allocates all the memory in one block.  Performance will be better, especially in the case where you want to iterate over every single element of the array.  (I think C++ should have included such a class in the standard.)

**EDIT**: I realized that my solution does have one weakness compared to yours.  If you decided to use one huge `std::vector` for all the rows instead of separate `std::vector`s, it wouldn't break your iterator-based API, but it would break my version.

Another option would be to return raw a pair of raw pointers instead of iterators.  They work in all the same places iterators do.  That would still expose the fact that rows are stored contiguously, so you could never store the elements of a single row in a linked list for example. But in my opinion, contiguous storage is so fundamental, and so important for anything that cares about performance, that it's totally fine to expose contiguousness in an API.

However, if it applies to your needs, I still think using a 2D array wrapper class is the best solution.